# how to split/cut video using vlc in command line after every N minute?

Tags: command-line, vlc, libvlc

how to split or cut a video using vlc in command line into 5 minute chucks? I know how to do it manually i just go to view->advanced controls and press the record to indicate the start time and press record again to indicate stop time now is there a way to do this in command line? if so can we also make vlc automatically cut/split the video every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I'd recommend to use FFmpeg. See [FFmpeg: How to split video efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651654/ffmpeg-how-to-split-video-efficiently)

The command to get the first 5 minutes would be:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:05:00 output1.avi
```

Comment: @reto...thanks for the suggestion I tried it and it worked :)

Comment: for those without ffmpeg, avconv does the same thing, check before installing ffmpeg:  `avconv -i inp.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 01:00:00 -t 0:30:00 out.avi`

Comment: Please, can you elaborate why you recommend using FFmpeg? Would you use it just for resizing/cutting or also for transcoding/compressing? Thank you

Comment: It does this particular job well and is freely available for various platforms. I do not have any personal experience for transcoding compression use cases, but I'm sure it'll do a fine job as well.