# ffmpeg to split mp4 file into segments... after first segment, audio unsynced

Tags: ffmpeg, mp4, video-editing

I've used the ffmpeg command line shown in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651654/ffmpeg-how-to-split-video-efficiently) to split MKV files perfectly for a long time.  Now i have some MP4 files that i'd like to split and at first it seemed to work, but every subsequent segment after the first has the audio not synced!  And by several seconds.

I've tried forcing keyframes (advice I found on some other sites) and that didn't help.

I tried a different program entirely (Avidemux) and it was able to split the file with proper output, but it was a LOT slower, taking upwards of 3 minutes vs less than 2 seconds with ffmpeg.  With Avidemux I was able to determine the exact position of the i-frame where I wanted to split, so thinking perhaps that was the syncing problem I tried that exact position (ie. 00:12:17.111 instead of 00:12:16 or whatever) but that didn't help either.

Is there an option I'm missing with ffmpeg to get it to properly sync audio to the video when splitting?

Comment: Try a different version of FFmpeg.  And, don't post FFmpeg CLI questions on Stack Overflow.  They're off-topic here.  Use SuperUser.com and you'll likely get a better response.

Comment: I was referencing a Stack Overflow FFMpeg CLI question so I just assumed if that Q was OK... so was this.  Just found it via Google... didn't really give it a 2nd thought, sorry.

Comment: FYI - updating FFmpeg didn't help at all.  Exact same issue.

Comment: You might try rolling back to an older version.  This definitely sounds like a bug.

Comment: Rolling back is a bad idea. Recent versions are always better with ffmpeg. Please delete this question here since you already reposted it on Super User.

Comment: If an admin wishes to delete it, I concur... however, I'm not going to delete it myself as doing so presents me with a warning about my account being blocked if i do so.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand WHY, but the issue was order of parameters.

In the linked example, the command is as follows:

```
ffmpeg -i input.avi -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:30:00 -t 00:30:00 output2.avi
```

Of course, I'm using mp4 instead of avi, but otherwise I was entering the command exactly as above and (with mp4) I was getting an out-of-sync audio result.  I accidentally stumpled onto this "fix"... if I instead enter the command thusly:

```
ffmpeg -ss 00:30:00 -i input.mp4 -vcodec copy -acodec copy -t 00:30:00 output2.mp4
```

I don't get the sync issues.  Why?  No idea.  But it works.  I've tried it a few times to confirm... making only that order of parameters change corrects the issue.

Comment: Using ffmpeg version N-72460-g11aa050 to copy AACs out of MP4s with -ss position and -t duration. First/normal parameter order produced good results. Second/changed parameter order produced bad results. The beginnings of all tracks after the first included the end of the previous track. This would be a bug.

Comment: I think when you see the beginnings of the tracks including the end of the previous track, it isn't really a "bug" but it has to do with position of the keyframes.

Comment: Okay @bcsteeve but regardless of what it has to do with, if there's no good reason for the altered parameter order to make a difference, and/or if the difference it makes and the reason for it is not documented, then that's a problem leading to wrong/bug-like output. Optimization suggestion: when the output is audio-only, ignore anything such as keyframes that affects only video, to the extent possible.

Comment: The weird thing is: if I use the 2nd syntax, the 2nd chunk is OK but VLC has problems navigating the first chunk (it sees its end time as that of the whole file); if I use the 1st syntax, the 1st chunk is OK but the 2nd chunk's audio is out of sync by 3 seconds.