# FFmpeg command to apply multiple filters and limit the final file size

Tags: macos, bash, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm using [ffmpeg](/questions/tagged/ffmpeg) command below to convert video to a format of the defined scale and in order to hardcode the subtitles

#### Original syntax

```
ffmpeg -i "Original File.mov"  -vf subtitles=Subtitles.srt -vf scale=1920:1080 \
       -crf 12 "Final File".mov
```

## Problem

I would like to expand this command further and:

- ensure that the produce file is *under* 2GB
- I would like to include additional parameters with [advanced subtitle options](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Subtitle-options), like setting the canvas size and fixing the potential delay

### Side notes

I reckon that in case of predefining the file size the [**`-crf 12`**](http://slhck.info/articles/crf) paramater will be redundant?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I was thinking of posting this on [Video Production Stacks](http://video.stackexchange.com/) but I came across very well received questions concerned *solely* with the [tag:ffmpeg] usage ([1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7333232/concatenate-two-mp4-files-using-ffmpeg), [2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5651654/ffmpeg-how-to-split-video-efficiently)); so I decided to post here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can sort of set an upper limit on file size by defining an average bitrate e.g.  `-b:v 4000k` and maximum bitrate `-maxrate 5000k -bufsize 5000k`, based on the duration of your video. as explained at FFmpeg [wiki](http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264#twopass). You can use CRF in place of `-b:v` but you'll need to keep the maxrate and bufsize.

To apply multiple filters, you specify them in one filterchain, separated by commas, so:

```
-vf subtitles=Subtitles.srt,scale=1920:1080
```

As far as I know, those advanced subtitle optionsare applicable to subtitles presented as a regular input, not via the hardcoding subtitles filter

Comment: Thanks very much, the linked wiki article suggests *2 pass* approach. Can I make it with one pass?

Comment: Sure, 2 pass produces better quality, but you can skip it.

Comment: So the syntax for two pass for both commands is identical with the difference that the first one mentioned *1 pass* and the other *2 pass*?

Comment: For single pass encoding, you would skip `-pass N` flag