# How to skip start frames with ffmpeg

Tags: php, ffmpeg

I have using ffmpeg to create short preview of videos...

```
$length = $length_video/5;

$ffmpeg_path." -i ".$content." -vf select='lt(mod(t\,".$length.")\,1)',setpts=N/FRAME_RATE/TB -af aselect='lt(mod(t\,".$length.")\,1)',asetpts=N/SR/TB -an ".$content_new.";
```

Actually this will create 5sec. video. and problem is because first frame is extracted from 0-1 sec.

There is any chance to skip first frame and extract next 5?

Problem is because first frame is actually useless because of video intro

Comment: Change to `" -ss 1 -i "` to skip the first second.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This *select* filter should skip the first 5 frames:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input_file -vf select="gte(n\, 5)" ...
```

For timespan it's even easier. Here's how you skip the first 30 seconds:

```
$ ffmpeg -i input_file -ss 30 ...
```

To skip the first 30 seconds and keep the next 120 seconds of the original video, add `-t`:

```
$ ffmpeg -t input_file -ss 30 -t 120 ...
```

```
-ss  time_off        set the start time offset
-t   duration        record or transcode "duration" seconds of audio/video
```

Both `-ss` and `-t` take a time duration:

> The following examples are all valid time duration:
>
> `55`
> 55 seconds
>
> `12:03:45`
> 12 hours, 03 minutes and 45 seconds
>
> `23.189`
> 23.189 seconds

None of these methods will be perfectly accurate due to the very mechanics of how video compression works (P and B frames can not stand on their own). **ffmpeg** will try to adjust accordingly:

> Note that in most formats it is not possible to seek exactly, so ffmpeg will seek to the closest seek point before position. When transcoding and `-accurate_seek` is enabled (the default), this extra segment between the seek point and position will be decoded and discarded. When doing stream copy or when `-noaccurate_seek` is used, it will be preserved.

Refer to the [ffmpeg documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html) for more.

Comment: Hmm this should be working good



``$length_skip = $length_video/2;

ffmpeg -ss $length_skip-i file....``